# non Distinct Counting of Attribute in SAP HANA Graphical View

Tags: sql, hana

I have data like:

```
ColumnA  ColumnB   ColumnC
Group1    Part1     A
Group1    Part1     B
Group1    Part2     C
Group2    Part3     B
Group2    Part3     C
Group3    Part2     A
```

Output:

```
  ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC  Count_Part
    Group1    Part1     A        1
    Group1    Part1     B        0
    Group1    Part2     C        1
    Group2    Part3     B        1
    Group2    Part3     C        0   
    Group3    Part2     A        1
```

The logic is if a part is repeated in a group then it should be counted as unique inside a group. but if same Part is in another group we count it again.

If I can create a Column like above, problem will be solved.

I tried making Calculate column:

```
If(isnull(ColumnB)=1 or ColumnB='',0,1)
```

But this is only giving me non unique count, by this Part1 will be counted twice in Group1 which should not be the case.

Comment: apologies, I didn't check the tag, deleted my comment as actually no idea if it is possible to do in SAP HANA

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured it out.

```
select ColumnA, count(ColumnB) 
from(select distinct ColumnA, ColumnB from Table1) 
group by ColumnA;
```

The FROM statement narrows the selectable area down to unique rows.

```
ColumnA  ColumnB
Group1    Part1     
Group1    Part2     
Group2    Part3     
Group3    Part2
```

Then from the above, the main SELECT statement grabs the Group# and the number of parts in the group. Then the data goes through GROUP BY to group the resulting count.

```
ColumnA  ColumnB
Group1    2     
Group2    1     
Group3    1
```